# E: The package linux-headers-4.4.0-65 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

I got this error while installing system updates. It looks like it might be due to dependency issues. Updated with `apt-get` and used `-f install`. I got this error:

```
E: The package linux-headers-4.4.0-65 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Could anyone suggest how to resolve this issue?